# discord.py having problems with praw embeding

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, praw

this is my code the embed part wont work

```
@Bot.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="MEME TIME", color=0x57d8e9)
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').top()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 100)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)
    embed.add_field(submission=submission)
    await ctx.send(Embed=embed)
```

Comment: If you are getting an error you might to post it here along with your question

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues.

- Embeds require a description. You can create an empty description by providing a bolded space: `** **`.
- Your add field code is wrong also. It doesn't have a `submission` field. It has a `name`, a `value` field, and an `inline` boolean.
- Your random command will always get the top post. It is not properly designed.

Here is an example modified from your code that should get the job done:

```
@Bot.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="MEME TIME", description="** **", color=0x57d8e9)
    randomPost = random.randint(1, 100)
    Listposts = [post for post in reddit.subreddit('memes').top(limit=100)]
    post = Listposts[randomPost]
    embed.add_field(name=post.title, value=post.author)
    embed.set_image(url=post.url)
    await ctx.send(Embed=embed)
```

A little tool to help you with embed structuring and design can be found [here](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/).